What movie includes a dialog about imaginary voices?
All I have to go on is the following lines of dialog : 

Female character: You're a voice in my head
Male character responds: You're a voice in mine
Female  character: You're a fucking hallucination

Its part of a techno song that just popped up in my spotify playlist called hallucination by the Edison Factor. I'm sure I heard this dialogue in a film but cannot think of it

Don't take it wrong, it's a simple note: By googling with the correct grammar, it's an easy search. Replacing "your" by "you're". Anyway, nice work for finding yourself the answer ;)

Wow..it's fight club. After some googling I dismissed it as the voice sounded female and I didn't recognise the males voice as Brad Pitt.
The sound of the voices were probably changed slightly as part of the track.

Wana curse you for forgetting fight club :p

You just broke the First rule!
